# Using containers with inherited classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl, polymorphism

So, I haven't used C++ that much in about 3 years and now I'm having some trouble using my inherited classes with the STL containers. I have seen this kind of question asked a couple of times, but couldn't understand exactly what was being done or why my code wouldn't work when it was very similar to the answers.

Basically I have two classes, R and RD, R is the base class and RD is the derived class. Each element has its neighbours, kind of like a graph, so an element r1's neighbours can be either of class R or RD. I thought I'd solved that by creating a private deque in R but whenever I access the elements in said deque they're never RD, only R. My code is kind of like this:

```
class R {
public:
    R();
    ~R();

    inline void queue(R* r) { neighbours.push_back(r); }
    inline R& getFirstNeighbour() { return neighbours.top(); }

    virtual void printSomething() { cout << "R" << endl; }
protected:
    deque<R*> neighbours;
}

class RD: public R {
public:
    RD();
    ~RD();

    void printSomething() { cout << "RD" << endl; }
    void doSomethingElse();
}
```

Whenever I get an element's first neighbour and call printSomething, I always get R. What am I doing wrong here? How should this be done?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `getFirstNeighbor()` won't compile - typo?. What are you passing to `queue`?

Comment: How are you constructing your objects?  The code here looks OK; there's nothing that would change the type of object pointed to by the pointers in `neighbours`

Comment: post the rest of your code.  `~R()` should be virtual btw

Comment: I'd guess in your real code, somewhere or other you're accidentally passing an `R` by value instead of passing a pointer to an `R`, so any `RD` objects get "sliced" to become `R` objects at that point. Hard to guess exactly where it's happening though.

Comment: @JerryCoffin This is how I'm setting things up
   `R r1, r2;
    RD r3, r4;

    r1.queue(&r1);
    r1.queue(&r4);
    r2.queue(&r1);
    r2.queue(&r3);`

Comment: Are you always enqueuing `r1` or is that a typo? More code please ...

Comment: Side note: you need to declare ~R() as virtual.

Comment: If you want to find quickly where RD becomes R, add to R a private copy ctor and a private assignment operator, and recompile.

Comment: With a few minor corrections, [the code](http://ideone.com/AxrrnM) seems to work.

Comment: @n.m. Good point.  There are very few occasions where you'd want to copy construct a polymorphic object, and practically none where you'd want to assign it.  Assignment, in particular, supposes value semantics, and polymorphism is more or less incompatible with values semantics.

Comment: Please, what is the real code of getFirstNeighbour()?

Comment: Well, I managed to solve it. The problem was when getting the neighbour. I was doing it like `R r1 = r.getFirstNeighbour();` when I should be doing `R* r1 = &r->getFirstNeighbour();`. I'm not sure if that's good practice but it worked for me. Thank you all for taking the time to help me

Answer (score 0):

Your code works but has a few mistakes (the constructor and destructors were missing "{ }", here is some valid code ( I use the std::deque here so I replaced the top() function by front() )

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class R {
public:
    R(){};
    ~R(){};
inline void queue(R* r) { neighbours.push_back(r); }


//Here is your error, look at the return : you need to dereference your neighbours.front():
inline R& getFirstNeighbour() { return *neighbours.front(); }

virtual void printSomething() { cout << "R" << endl; }
protected:
    deque<R*> neighbours;
};


class RD: public R {
public:
    RD(){};
    ~RD(){};

    void printSomething() { cout << "RD" << endl; }
    void doSomethingElse();
};


int main()
{
R r;
//R with 3 neighbors
r.queue(new RD());


r.getFirstNeighbour().printSomething(); // Printing RD :)


return 0;
}
```